# Force a specific pattern into a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I have a web page with a text box on it.  Currently through some javascript the text box only allows you to type numbers or a minus sign or dash - .

My question is  that I would like a way to further force the input to be in the form of 3 numbers followed by a '-' then followed by 2 more numbers and that's it. So it looks like ###-## every time its entered. I've tried lots of ways so far like this code.

```
<input type="text" name="Item1" id = "Item1" value="" type="number" pattern="(0){3}-(0){2}" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/></input>
```

But the pattern didn't work.  Any suggestions to where I should start some research or sample code would be great. I was hoping it might be achievable in CSS but javascript will do.

Comment: AFAIK, `pattern` won't work with `type="number"`. FYI, you have multiple `type` attributes

Comment: are you looking for a Javascript implementation for this or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> input to be in the form of 3 numbers followed by a '-' then followed by 2 more numbers

```js
let inputHandler = function(e) {
  var tmp = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').split('');
  if (3 < tmp.length) {
    tmp.splice(3, 0, '-');
  }
  this.value = tmp.join('').substr(0, 6);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll('[name=Item1]').forEach(function(inp) {
    inp.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="Item1" /><input type="text" name="Item1" /><input type="text" name="Item1" />
```

Comment: This is perfect but all answers were good thanks guys...This one wins because you cant type it in wrong and it adds a dash automatically..so awesome

Answer (score 2):

Following pattern should do the trick.

```
[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}
```

As in

```
<input type="text" name="Item1" id = "Item1" value="" type="number" pattern="[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you are looking for is :

```
[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}
```

Expanding on this,

```
[0-9]        : accepts any value from 0 to 9
<pattern>{x} : specifies how many times <pattern> should be matched
[0-9]{3}     : match value from 0 to 9 three times
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="Item1" id = "Item1" value="" type="number" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some regular pattern for text input in html.
you can use pattern that I wrote it below.

**Email**

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$">
```

**URL**

```
<input type="url" id="website" name="website"pattern="https?://.+" >
```

**Password**
Although have at least 8 -- one uppercase + number

```html
<input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}">
```

these are so use full if you want to make your own design you should learn
regular expression on [RegExp w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp).